# Trying to install Ring Doorbell 3 which has 2 wires where the existing button has 3 wires

Tags: wiring, doorbell

Trying to replace my doorbell with the Ring Doorbell 3 and not sure how to identify which are the wires I need to connect to the ring doorbell. I'm replacing an intercom doorbell with 3 wires and I know the ring won't work with the intercom which I'm fine with.

Here is a pic of the inside of the intercom doorbell.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @isherwood Looks more like `-`, `E`, and `1` to me.

Comment: If it helps answer the question, I think this is a little more info on the doorbell I'm trying to replace :  https://www.aiphone.com/products/le-d